# How to relay dataset/datatable from Tomcat to a .NET application?

Tags: .net, xml, tomcat, datatable, ado

I need to provide data to a DataTable in a .NET application from a servlet hosted in Tomcat.
It seems tempting to just stream back XML the .NET application can just pupulate using DataTable.ReadXML. Is that the proper road to go down ?
And not the least; are there existing Java components that can help me with this on the Tomcat side ?

Edit. The .NET application is a GUI application not a web application/service.

Comment: Why does it need to be a DataTable?

Comment: A dataset is a .NET component, not Java... where did the Java app get it in the first place ? as an XML file ?

Comment: @RichardOD Because the .NET application already written uses it. One could always rewrite it to use something else, but why bother ?

@Thomas Levesque The Java app will fetch it from an SQL database. Sure, one could toss away Tomcat. Or the .NET app, and have either Java or .NET on both ends. Which is not realistic given the time already spent on these 2 former seperate entities which given buisiness requirements now have to talk together.

Answer (score 1):

DataSet and DataTable are implementation specific. They are not the sort of thing to expose from a web service, as they hare how you happen to be implementing your service, and have nothing to do with what the service is trying to do.

Instead, define the data that you need transferred, create a class containing that data (and just that data), and have the servelet send that data to the .NET service.